# IBM MQA (Mobile Quality Assurance) Crashes in iOS 9

Tags: ios9

When running an iOS app that is instrumented with IBM MQA (Mobile Quality Assurance) running iOS 9, it crashes with the following error message:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I prevent this crash?

Comment: I'm not sure sure you downvoted the question and answer. The answer to how you prevent the crash is in the answer. The process to disable it is very simple. In XCode, just change the "Enable Bitcode" property in the Build Settings from Yes to No.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but others had flagged this as potential spam due to your undisclosed relationship with the product in question. I also formatted this into a proper question. In the future, you might want to make it clear that you work on this product at IBM in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS MQA SDK does not contain bitcode so you must disable bitcode for this target for architecture arm64. If not, you will receive the error below:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is a new option in iOS 9 to help reduce the footprint of the apps for WatchOS.

The process to disable it is very simple. In XCode, just change the "Enable Bitcode" property in the Build Settings from Yes to No.

Please see the newly released technote for more information: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21967406